# VERY small Png image not showing in frontend?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, gallery-image

I have looked for an answer with no sucess.

In my 1.7.0.2 Magento I can upload a QR code png image, dimensions 164 x 164, size 400 bytes, it shows fine in the admin area, but will not display in front end (just shows "Loading" forever...).

I have tried different images from the QR code generator, all almost identical size, all fail on frontend.
They do work if I convert them to GIF.

The original Png files DO work on my 1.9 Magento installation (on the same server).

Can anyone suggest why that might be, and how I can fix this?

Regards, Paul